# How do I make the document parameters in Altium visible?

Tags: schematics, altium, s-parameters

I am currently using a student license for Altium and I am trying to edit the "title" and "drawn by" parameters in my schematics. However, I am unable to do so due to a locked visible option when editing a document parameter.
**Does anybody know how to unlock this so I can make my parameters visible?**

Comment: Can  you show (printscreen) what you mean by "locked visible" option?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the values by right-clicking, and then going to options->document parameters.

The standard altium template doesn't contain the so called "special strings".
So either you have to add the text manually to the field (e.g. type =Engineer) or you have to change the template so it includes it.

A tutorial by altium explaining the special strings is given [here](http://videos.altium.com/trainingcenter/player.html?ep=1095).

*Edit:* Alternatively you can go to Design>Templates and select a template designed by altium. Those templates have the special string already placed so you should see the document parameters.

*Edit2:* 
The parameters in a fully registered altium still look like this:

[image]

It is not the visible checkbox that is used to put them into the schematic, look at the tutorial for more info.